# Find the minimum of the value $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ not all equal postive integer,and such
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{5}a+b}{\sqrt{5}b+c}\in Q$$
Find the minimum of the value  $$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}$$

Comment: If you rationalize the denominator, then the first condition given is equivalent to $b^2 = ac$. From here, it is a question of two variables.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=4$. Then we have
$$
h(a,b,c):={\sqrt{5}a+b \over \sqrt{5}b+c} = 
{\sqrt{5}+2 \over 2\sqrt{5}+4} = {1\over2} \in \mathbb{Q},
$$
and
$$
f(a,b,c):={a^2+b^2+c^2 \over a+b+c} = {1+4+16\over1+2+4} = {21\over7} = 3.
$$
We will now show that under the given conditions $f(a,b,c)$ cannot be less than $3$.

It is not difficult to check that any combination of 
$\{a,b,c\}\subset[1,8]$ either produces an irrational $h(a,b,c)$ or gives $f(a,b,c)\ge3$ for $h(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Q} \ $ (provided that $a,b,c$ are not all equal).

On the other hand, if $$m:=\max(a,b,c)\ge9,$$ then we always have 
$f(a,b,c)>{m\over3}\ge3$, because the denominator $a+b+c$ is less than $3m$, while the numerator $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is greater than $m^2$.

Therefore, under the given conditions, the minimum value of $f(a,b,c)$ is $3$.

The minimum value $3$ is attained for 
$$a=1, \quad b=2, \quad c=4,$$
as well as for
$$a=4, \quad b=2, \quad c=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$( a\sqrt 5\; +b)/(b\sqrt 5\;+c)\in \mathbb Q$ iff $a=bx$ and $c=b/x$ for some  $x\in \mathbb Q^+.$ Otherwise we would have $\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q.$

So $(a^2+b^2+c^2)/(a+b+c)=b\cdot \frac {x^2+1+x^{-2}}{x+1+x^{-1}}=f(b,x).$

We have $x\ne 1$, else $a=b=c.$

Now $f(b,x)-b=b\frac {(x-1)^2}{x}>0.$

So if $b\geq 3$ then $f(b,x)>b\geq 3.$

We cannot have $b=1$, else $\min (a,c)=\min (bx,b/x)<b=1.$

Now if $b=2$ then $1\leq \min (a,c)=\min (bx,b/x)=\min (2x,2/x)<2$, implying $(a=1 \land x=1/2\land  c=4)$, or $(c=1\land  x=2\land a=4)$, with $f(b,x)=f(2,1/2)=f(2,2)=3.$

Comment: I originally made an algebra error and thought  I had $f(b,x)>\max (bx,b/x)>b.$ When I saw the error I tried calculating $f(b,x)-b$ and was pleasantly surprised. "Algebra is generous. She often gives more than what is asked"-- L.Euler.